# Is there a cheap way I can do a Bell inequality experiment?

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, bells-inequality

My work is almost completely theoretical/computational.  But I'd really like to do a Bell inequality experiment just so I can personally see this (the best way to learn something is hands-on, right?)

What all do I need do this?  I suppose I can use two lasers and polarizing filters, but how exactly do I emit just one photon at a time?  I actually feel kind of stupid asking this; I don't even know the basics of how these experiments are performed.  Is there something expensive I need?

I wonder if my physics department would let an engineering student borrow their resources...

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Those are not exactly table top experiments. Especially if you want to do it properly. Read the papers by Alain Aspect to get an impression of what's involved and then decide yourself if you feel up to it.

Comment: A nice news & views article from Aspect published in Nature is available here: http://www.ece.rice.edu/~kono/ELEC565/Aspect_Nature.pdf

Comment: You may be interested in this page : http://people.whitman.edu/~beckmk/QM/ and http://www.advlab.org/pdf/imm2013_Beck_qo_parts_list_Jan_2012.pdf

Comment: The most expensive part will be the single-photon detectors (a few 1,000$). Then, you cannot use two lasers because the photon would not be entangled. You need an entangled photon source (usually a suatably pumped BBO crystal)

Comment: @Jonas While it is worth reading papers about what the pro kit looks like, it is generally true that cheaper and easier ways of demonstrating phenomena develop in the decades following their first measurements.

Comment: I'm a university undergraduate physics lab experiment designer. I've been looking for a cheap way to do this type of experiment (and do it in an educationally valuable way) for years. I can tell you, there is no such way. The easiest particles to entangle are photons, which means you need single photon detectors and crystals like BBO. Very expensive stuff. We're talking at least a couple thousand for one set. That's sort of within my budget, but I'd never lend it out to someone for a home project.

Comment: Let me be clear, you could duct tape together a working setup for cheap without some of the fancier gear, but you wouldn't be able to pull much from it. These experiments have a big problem with loopholes and confounding variables. In order to make it rigorous and meaningful, it's going to become expensive